# Configure Trackpoint sensitivity using a GUI

Tags: hardware, configuration, thinkpad, trackpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T61, which uses a Trackpoint. Every time I reinstall Ubuntu, the default sensitivity settings are much too low (it feels like I really have to **push** to move the cursor).

I've been changing this manually for quite a few releases now, creating startup scripts to automatically change obscure configuration files as denoted at ThinkWiki.org. About a year ago, I found [gpointing-device-settings](http://live.gnome.org/GPointingDeviceSettings), which looked like the answer to my prayers (and in some ways it is). Unfortunately, despite the description and [pictures](http://live.gnome.org/GPointingDeviceSettings?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=GPointingDeviceSettings_TrackPoint.png) on the gnome.org page, I cannot use this GUI to control the Trackpoint sensitivity (it's not an option).

I've also heard of configure-trackpoint, but last I tried (a year ago) it didn't save your sensitivity settings (you need to make a startup script). I really dislike opening a Terminal and/or creating scripts to set my Trackpoint mouse sensitivity. Is there any way around all this using a GUI? It feels like there should be.

Answer (score 2):

Use the settings in **Applications ▸ Mouse Preferences ▸ Pointer Speed**.

I've had no issues with using this to adjust the sensitivity of the TrackPoint on my ThinkPad X60.